# What is the purpose of an empty value assignment in JavaScript (not null, undefined, etc)

Tags: javascript

I understand this:

```
let blah = null;
let blah = undefined;
let blah;
```

What I don’t understand is this:

```
    let obj = {}
      // notice the empty value assignment and the assignment that immediately follows
    obj.blah = 
    obj.blah = function(params) {
      // some code
    }
```

Is the empty assignment the same as `let obj.blah;`? I’ve seen this in a few npm packages where the key is provided a value directly beneath the empty value assignment of the same key. Is there a particular purpose to writing code this way? I’m refactoring a package to streamline its use, and I don’t want to simply delete this because of my ignorance. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It’s not the same. `let obj.blah` throws an error

Comment: There's absolutely no point to that line, you can just delete it. Probably an error left over from a previous revision of the code.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, so what happens in this case? I feel totally lost, as I’ve been unable to find a resource that explains this.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery, so an editing oversight? Gotcha. There are several files where this occurs. As a result, it looked intentional to me.

Comment: `obj.blah = ` is probably a typo. It's pointless. As for the first assignment `let obj = {}` it _is_ needed otherwise `obj.blah` would throw an error.

Comment: @evolutionxbox right. The object declaration and the function assignment make sense. It was the intermediary line that had me confused. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's equivalent to

```
obj.blah = ( obj.blah = function () {} );
```

There's absolutely no reason to do that.

Comment: Okay, that actually clarifies a great deal for me. What I’ve been finding while reworking this code is a whole lot of `this` hacks. It wouldn’t surprise me if this was another hack they were using to avoid properly passing `this`. Thank you.